# Use pyarrow and json.dump to save json file in hdfs

Tags: python, json, hdfs, pyarrow

I am trying to save json file in HDFS using pyarrow. Here is what my code looks like.

```
from pyarrow import hdfs
fs = hdfs.connect(driver='libhdfs')
with fs.open(outputFileVal1, 'wb') as fp:
    json.dump(list(value1set), fp)
```

This gives an error saying `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

When I try joblib.dump or pickle.dump instead it works, but it doesn't save in json format. Is there any way to save json file directly to hdfs using pyarrow.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you may need to use a wrapper that will encode the data written by `json.dump` to binary, using `chunk.encode('utf8')`. Something like

```
class Utf8Encoder(object):

    def __init__(self, fp):
        self.fp = fp

    def write(self, data):
        if not isinstance(data, bytes):
            data = data.encode('utf-8')
        self.fp.write(data)
```

Then you can write

```
json.dump(..., Utf8Encoder(fp))
```